# Google APIs not updating in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I am using the Google Plugin for Eclipse (4.4) to manage my Google App Engine project. I am using several Google APIs, which I have added to the project with the plugin. Google's documentation states that the APIs are indicated with `[Update available]` when a new version is present. However, I do not get these updates.

For example: I now use the Gmail API 1.18, but I would like to have 1.21 (the newest). Manually overwriting some jars is not what I want.

Does anyone know why these updates aren't pushed? Anyone with the same problem and maybe a solution?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I used to have problems with the eclipse plugin for app engine and then i switched to maven. That's something i generally recommend when you're having a hard time with IDE plugins.

Comment: I need to try this. So what all do I need to do to achieve this? In maven shall I add the App Engine SDK dependencies and what else? Will google deploy button work? I am also struggling update the project to use the latest GAE SDK.